# Capturing groups with sed command

Tags: sed

I have strings like below

```
 _c_VehCfg1_oCAN00_f276589c_In_Int_buf *pVehCfg1_oCAN00_f276589c_In_IntBuf = (_c_VehCfg1_oCAN00_f276589c_In_Int_buf *)can_Msg_tmp_buffer;
```

I want replace `can_Msg_tmp_buffer` with `ptr` as below

```
_c_VehCfg1_oCAN00_f276589c_In_Int_buf *pVehCfg1_oCAN00_f276589c_In_IntBuf = (_c_VehCfg1_oCAN00_f276589c_In_Int_buf *)ptr;
```

I have tried `sed` as below

```
echo  "_c_VehCfg1_oCAN00_f276589c_In_Int_buf *pVehCfg1_oCAN00_f276589c_In_IntBuf = (_c_VehCfg1_oCAN00_f276589c_In_Int_buf *)can_Msg_tmp_buffer;" | sed  's/\(_C_[[:alnum:]_]*IntBuf = [[:alnum:]_]*\)can_Msg_tmp_buffer/1\ptr/g'
```

Still I'm not getting expected result instead `sed` output is same as input.

The problem is I have strings like below also

```
_c_GW_C4_oCAN00_f276589c_In_Moto_buf *pGW_C4_oCAN00_f276589c_In_MotoBuf = (_c_GW_C4_oCAN00_f276589c_In_Moto_buf *)can_Msg_tmp_buffer;
```

I only want to replace where `type` is ending with `_Int_buf` not `_Moto_buf`.

Comment: I'm not sure why a close vote was registered against this question with reason `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")`. The Q clearly has an attempt made (need to scroll through to see the `sed` command) and a valid i/p and an expected o/p provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets extremely convoluted to match individual words with a regex and get a captured group out of it. One way would be to work with known parts of the string which are guaranteed to occur.

For your case, using the strings `_In_IntBuf` and `can_Msg_tmp_buffer;` we try to uniquely identify those pattern of lines and do the substitution

```
sed  's/\(.*\)_In_IntBuf = \(.*\)can_Msg_tmp_buffer;/\1_In_IntBuf = \2ptr;/'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are ok with `awk` try following.

```
awk '/_In_IntBuf =/{sub(/can_Msg_tmp_buffer/,"ptr")} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in above code.

Comment: Its ok I only needed one working solution, as I'm working with huge `C` code `sed` command provided in above answer helped me.